# EPUB reader for *BSD/Linux

Tags: linux, software-rec, bsd, epub

What are the best native EPUB readers for *BSD/Linux. Browser add-ons are not an option.

I prefer non-Qt applications but you can share Qt applications if you want. If possible, I want a program that remembers the page I was last viewing.

Answer (score 6):

I looked into this recently, and a lot of people pointed to [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/). I think it's primarily a converter and library app, but it has a built-in viewer as well.

Comment: And the viewer is conveniently called E-book Viewer. It does remember the page; it's the only (IMHO) valid reason for using Calibre as a package.

Comment: There are many valid uses of calibre.  BTW, calibre's `ebook-viewer` has the same UI problems as the rest of calibre which suffers greatly from NIH-syndrome and the author's idiosyncrasies....it works well enough for the most part, but I wish it used standard UI conventions (a standard menu bar instead of the giant and sometimes incomprehensible icons would be a good start).

Comment: @CraigSanders, can you suggest any good alternatives? (to the converter/reader parts of Calibre, I don't care much about the library functionality)

Comment: There isn't really anything that competes with calibre for ebook reading or conversion.  IMO the UI is tolerable because the underlying features (library, indexing, reading, conversion) work so well...shame the UI is so weird and clunky.  However, if you don't want to use the main calibre GUI, calibre's `ebook-viewer` can run standalone, and `ebook-convert` is a command-line conversion tool.

Comment: Jugding from this [discussion about an exploit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/calibre/+bug/885027) one should really careful when using calibre.

Answer (score 5):

Try [FBReader](http://www.fbreader.org/). It loads the last page you were reading by default and probably has all the features you could want. **It is a Qt app** (and new to the Linux desktop), but I've used it for several years on Android and it keeps getting better.

It's open source, reads many file formats, supports bookmarks, local/online catalogs, and has lots of customization options. Recently installed it on my Gnome Shell desktop and it integrates fairly well with the UI.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not interested in library management and other extra features, you might want to try [CoolReader](http://coolreader.org/e-index.htm). It does use Qt, but it's light, quick and very easy to use. It also remembers the pages you were last reading.

Edit: A fine alternative is the multiplatform [Quivi](http://quivi.sourceforge.net). Also fast and sufficiently configurable. I believe that remembering what page you were on is in the to-do list so keep an eye out for it.

Edit2: I have started using [mcomix](http://mcomix.sourceforge.net/). Less configurable than quivi, but still very well-made.

Answer (score 1):

> Lucidor is a computer program for reading and handling e-books.
>   Lucidor supports e-books in the EPUB file format, and catalogs in the
>   OPDS format.

http://lucidor.org/lucidor/

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question and noticed yours in "related" questions sidebar.

You might find my answer helpful there: [Recommendation for an eBook reader for GNOME](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547260/256816).

Comment: Yes, your reply was useful. Thanks!.