# Recommendation for an eBook reader for Gnome

Tags: gnome, software-rec, epub, ebooks

There are eBook readers for Android, there's Okular for KDE, and stuff like that, but what I want, is an eBook (ePub format) reader for my normal Linux desktop.

I know there's [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/), which goes way beyond being just an eBook reader, and theres [FBReader](http://www.fbreader.org/), Which doesn't really work as of yet. Given that eBooks have been around for several years now, I'd assume, more software would've sprung up by now.

Comment: Just to clarify, you probably mean "an eBook reader that doesn't require a bunch of KDE libs", right? Presumably one that's GTK-based but doesn't require Gnome libs would be fine. Presumably also one that's QT-based without being KDE-based. Not that I know of any beyond Calibre. The expression "for Gnome" just struck me as odd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of others are [Cool Reader](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crengine/) and [AZARDI](http://azardi.infogridpacific.com/azardi-download.html). Lucidor was another, but development stopped and the website is down (although you can still find the debs e.g. [here](http://www.mobileread.com/forums/archive/index.php/t-81172.html)). In my opinion AZARDI is the best of these.

Update: Lucidor seems to be back in development and [its website](http://lucidor.org/lucidor/) is back online.

Answer (score 7):

I recently came across a decent eBook reader for GNOME (or any desktop environment based on GTK) called [Foliate](https://johnfactotum.github.io/foliate/). It relatively new, and currently under active development, yet it has a lot of interesting features:

- It supports .epub, .mobi, .azw, and .azw3 files
- Reading progress slider with chapter marks
- Quick dictionary lookup with *Wiktionary*, *Wikipedia*, and *[dictd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dictd)*, or translate a text with *Google Translate*
- Touchpad gestures
- Basic text-to-speech support with *eSpeak NG* and *Festival*

---

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Calibre comes with an application called E-Book Viewer. I just ended up discovering that after installing Calibre, and it's both light weight and supports most major formats.